# Can you define a vacuum state on a Cauchy surface?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spacetime, vacuum

In the functional approach, one can define a [vacuum state of a scalar field](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9605004) at a point in time as:

$$\Psi_0[\phi] \propto e^{-\int \int \phi(x) G(x-y) \phi(y) dx^3 dy^3 }$$

Where $G$ is some specified function. I wonder if instead of choosing a flat time-slice, instead one took a general Cauchy surface $\Sigma$, for example defining a function $\tau(x)$ which had a different time for every position, how would this vacuum state change?

Or does a vacuum state only make sense if you foliate time into flat parallel time-slices?

I think you should be able to define a vacuum whatever way you slice up time since the excitations of the vacuum shouldn't depend on how you foliate time. But my intuition is failing me here.

I have a feeling the answer might be:

$$\Psi_\tau[\phi] \propto \exp\left(-\int \int \phi(x) \Delta(x-y;\tau(x)-\tau(y)) \phi(y) \sqrt{1+(\partial_\mu \tau(x))^2 }\sqrt{1+(\partial_\mu \tau(y))^2 }dx^3 dy^3 \right)$$

where $\Delta(x,t)$ is a Feynman-like propagator. But not certain. Especially about the integration measure.

Or if $X^\mu(x,y,z)$ is the 4D coordinates of the Cauchy surface:

$$\Psi_X[\phi] \propto \exp\left(-\int \int \phi(x) \Delta(X(x)-X(y)) \phi(y) \sqrt{\det \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial X^\mu(x) \partial X^\nu(x)} \sqrt{\det \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial  X^\mu(y) \partial X^\nu(y)}dx^3 dy^3 \right)$$

which in the above case $X^\mu(x,y,z) = [x,y,z,\tau(x,y,z)]$

This seems like it could be right but I'm not sure. Perhaps the measure should be embedded into the definition of $\phi(x)$. i.e. $\phi(x) \equiv \Phi(X(x))\sqrt{\det \eta_{\mu\nu}\partial X^\mu(x) \partial X^\nu(x)} $ ?

**Edit:** Now I'm starting to think $G_{\Sigma}(x-y)$ is the sum of amplitudes of paths that start on the Cauchy and end on it but never pass through it. So it is not so simple as I wrote here (especially for non-flat Cauchy surfaces) and maybe there is no simple way to write it in terms of $X$ or $\tau$.

Comment: Check out the book "Introduction to Quantum Effects in Gravity" by Mukhanov and Winitzki